# How to merge indicators/variables?

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I have a problem with my data analysis (with structural equation modelling -SEM). In detail, I have 3 indicators/variables that are quite close together, the existence of all of them in the model might be redundant (reliability composite is a bit high, at around 0.91-0.93). So I am thinking about simplifying some measurement indicators, and some ideas comes to my mind as:

1. Eliminate one of the redundant indicators. The one to be removed might be indicators with lower scope (i.e. more particular ones) so the most general indicator will be remain.
2. Using factor analysis with 3 indicators (regression approach) to calculate the factor score, and using this new factor score as a indicator to represent for the 3 indicators mentioned. The result shows that 1 factor can represent for about 82% of variances.

I really want to hear for your comments about the two approach above. And I am also looking for 3rd or 4th approach to solve this issues from you. If you know any references related to this problem, please help me!

Thank you so much!

Comment: A point of clarification: by *redundancy* are you referring to collinearity and feature dependence or do you mean linear combinations? Depending on which type of redundancy you're encountering, the solutions would be different. *Collinearity* can be decomposed into nonessential and essential. Many times, simply centering continuous features to a mean of zero can blunt *nonessential* collinearity, with any remaining dependence considered *essential*. However, your description is of indicators. If you have *linear combinations*, models aren't estimable and the offending variable shd be dropped.

Comment: Thank u for your answer, Johnson. Indicator in my question is actually variable that used as a measurement unit for another latent variable (construct). I am afraid that two indicators are quite close together so that they could potentially measure the same phenomena (or the same aspect of the latent variable in its reflective measurement model). So as Hair et al (2017) in his book called this issue as a redundant indicators and it should be minimised because redundant indicators might affect to the validity of the model as well as boost error term correlation.

Comment: However, collinearity is not an issue, as all VIF ratios are smaller than the threshold of 5.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about both the book reference to Hair (2017), i.e., its title, as well as the meaning of *redundant*. I have no idea what 'quite close together' means, Given that they are indicators, have you looked at their crosstab? Why not post a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two reasons indicators may be highly correlated with each other: 1) they are both reliable measures of the latent variable, or 2) their errors are correlated due to some other factor (observed or unobserved). If the former is true, then you should absolutely keep both in your model; removing one will reduce the precision of your estimates. If the latter is true, you can remove one, but a better strategy might be fitting a CFA with the errors of the indicators correlated. In `lavaan` this can be done with `Y1 ~~ Y2`.

To test if the latter is true, try fitting models with and without that extra correlation and see which one fits better. If adding the correlation doesn't improve fit, then you just have good measures of the latent variable and should retain the items. If fit improves with the correlation, you should add the correlation in your CFA or remove one of the indicators.

Comment: Hi, very interesting response, I was wondering if you have any reference discussing this? (i.e., the possible reasons the indicators are correlated)